# Iterating over selection with query of an HDFStore

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a very large table in an HDFStore of which I would like to select a subset using a query and then iterate over the subset chunk by chunk. I would like the query to take place *before* the selection is broken into chunks, so that all of the chunks are the same size.

The documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#iterator) seems to indicate that this is the default behavior but is not so clear. However, it seems to me that the chunking is actually taking place *before* the query, as shown in this example:

```
In [1]: pd.__version__
Out[1]: '0.13.0-299-gc9013b8'

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'number': np.arange(1,11)})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   number
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10

[10 rows x 1 columns]


In [4]: with pd.get_store('test.h5') as store:
            store.append('df', df, data_columns=['number'])

In [5]: evens = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

In [6]: with pd.get_store('test.h5') as store:
            for chunk in store.select('df', 'number=evens', chunksize=5):
                print len(chunk)

        2
        3
```

I would expect only a single chunk of size 5 if the querying were happening before the result is broken into chunks, but this example gives two chunks of lengths 2 and 3.

Is this the intended behavior and if so is there an efficient workaround to give chunks of the same size without reading the table into memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think when I wrote that, the intent was to use *chunksize* of the results of the query. I think it was changed as was implementing it. The chunksize determines sections that the query is applied, and then you iterate on those. The problem is you don't apriori know how many rows that you are going to get.

However their IS a way to do this. Here is the sketch. Use `select_as_coordinates` to actually execute your query; this returns an `Int64Index` of the row number (the coordinates). Then apply an iterator to that where you select based on those rows.

Something like this (this makes a nice recipe, will include in the docs I think):

```
In [15]: def chunks(l, n):
        return [l[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(l), n)]
   ....: 

In [16]: with pd.get_store('test.h5') as store:
   ....:     coordinates = store.select_as_coordinates('df','number=evens')
   ....:     for c in chunks(coordinates, 2):
   ....:         print store.select('df',where=c)
   ....:        

   number
1       2
3       4

[2 rows x 1 columns]


   number
5       6
7       8

[2 rows x 1 columns]


   number
9      10

[1 rows x 1 columns]
```